# Is Typecscript 100% compatible with IE9 - if not will it advise what it can't do while you code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer-9

Does Typescript always transpile code (ES6->ES5) into something suitable for IE9.  If yes can you provide evidence as I can’t find anything that categorically says all valid ES6 code will be transpiled to work in IE9. (Various sources suggest it can, but not clear if that a general thing or full on yes it just works)

If not, does it warn or give errors to say that you can’t use feature X.
For example I see from the Babel site (https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/ ) that it can’t transpile or polyfil Proxies, so I’m guessing if it can’t change a Proxy into valid pre-ES6 code then Typescript will have the same issue?

Again if I look at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ and say open up “Destructuring, declarations” then it shows Babel with 21/22 and TS with only 15/22.  Does this mean that TS can’t work with as much as Babel? If I use TS, will it warn me if I try to use such syntax.

Comment: yes, TS dont do as much as babel and It wont warn you if it is valid TS syntax normally

Comment: If that's the case (and why I'm a bit confused) looking at this answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669753/using-angular-2-with-older-browsers-thanks-to-typescript it suggests that TS will go down to ES3. So how can they say it goes down to ES3 if its not 100%?

I want to use TS, but I need to support IE8 (so will probably not be using the latest and greatest ES6 features) - but what happens when I request my code to go down to say ES5 and it can't transpile a portion of the code as I've used some latest feature in ES6?

Comment: Should say IE9 rather than 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript code generated by the TypeScript compiler doesn't need a runtime library. This is a design choice.

In the ES6 improvement, two things:

1. New ES6 **syntax**;
2. New ES6 **API**.

New ES6 syntax like `class`, arrow functions, `const`, `let`, `for of` are well converted to ES3, the generated code will run on IE8.

TypeScript doesn't provide any API. Some ES6 API can be polyfilled: `Promise`, `Array.from`, etc. So, we can use TypeScript with [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), for example.

Some API, like `Proxy`, can not be polyfilled at all.

> does it warn or give errors to say that you can’t use feature X

Yes, but compared to ES3 or ES5 instead of IE8 or IE9.

You still have to know your target browsers.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.
Think I'm still confusing myself looking at the different tables from https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#typescript 
and 
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#
and then I listen to talks that say TS encompasses all ES6, but from the tables they suggest otherwise.

Comment: @delp The implementation [is still being](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap). When TypeScript claims it is a superset of JavaScript, it is not because all the JS features are already implemented. But you can take a file `file.js`, rename it to `file.ts`, then continue to work. You cannot do that if you want to switch your code to CoffeeScript. Like SCSS (but not SASS) comparing to CSS: it is the same language, with some additional improvements.